# DAM Asset Renditions - Getting cq5dam.thumbnail.48.48.png rendition but need the original rendition

Tags: java, aem

```
String itemPath = "/content/dam/global-abc/mcos/benefra/nl/custom/product-images/25-nl-107855/fact3.jpg";

String thumbnailUrl = itemPath;

if (assetManager != null) {                        
   Asset asset = assetManager.getAsset(itemPath);

   thumbnailUrl = asset.listRenditions().hasNext() ?
                  asset.listRenditions().next().getPath() : itemPath;

}
```

**asset.listRenditions().next().getPath() gives /content/dam/global-abc/mcos/benefra/nl/custom/product-images/25-nl-107855/fact3.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.48.48.png which will reduce the clarity of the image at UI end. Need to increase the resolution or get original image**

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:

I am only going to mention the "old" Asset API in `com.day.cq.dam.api`. There is a newer API in `com.adobe.granite.asset.api` which is different and lacks some features, which is why I usually prefer to use the "old" API.

---

There are several ways to get renditions in AEM and all of them come with advantages and disadvantages.

Before I start to explain a few ways to get renditions, there are two rules you should follow to make your live easier:

1. Never expect thumbnail or web renditions to exist.
2. Never use the original rendition except for downloads.

You wrote:

> Need to increase the resolution or get original image.

If you just want to get the original rendition, you can simply use:

```
Rendition rendition = asset.getOriginal();
```

But if you want to get *a* thumbnail or web rendition you should use one of the `RenditionPicker`.

To get a thumbnail rendition you can use:

```
PrefixRenditionPicker picker = new PrefixRenditionPicker(DamConstants.PREFIX_ASSET_THUMBNAIL, true)
Rendition rendition = picker.getRendition(asset);
```

This will give you the *first* thumbnail rendition that the picker will find. In theory you could force a certain thumbnail rendition by extending the code like this:

```
PrefixRenditionPicker picker = new PrefixRenditionPicker(DamConstants.PREFIX_ASSET_THUMBNAIL + ".319", true)
Rendition rendition = picker.getRendition(asset);
```

This would return the `319px` thumbnail rendition with the name `cq5dam.thumbnail.319.319.png`. But remember, there is no guarantee that this rendition exists. If there is no rendition with this name the `RenditionPicker` from above will simply return the `original` rendition (because we used `true` as second parameter).

The same process can be used to get the web rendition. You can either use the rendition picker from above and just use another constant:

```
PrefixRenditionPicker picker = new PrefixRenditionPicker(DamConstants.PREFIX_ASSET_WEB, true)
Rendition rendition = picker.getRendition(asset);
```

Or you use the the dedicated `WCMRenditionPicker`:

```
WCMRenditionPicker picker = new WCMRenditionPicker();
Rendition rendition = picker.getRendition(asset);
```

But as before, this will return the *first* rendition that is found or *null* if none is found.

Depending on your use case you might want to create your own `RenditionPicker` by implementing the following interface:

```
com.day.cq.dam.api.RenditionPicker
```

There is also another API I want to mention which is `com.day.cq.dam.commons.util.UIHelper`. This class contains a few interesting methods like:

```
getBestfitRendition(Asset asset, int width)
```

This method would allow you to specify a desired `width` and it will try to find the *nearest* best fitting rendition. This can be also quite handy in certain situations.

Links:

1. [Asset Javadoc](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/Asset.html)
2. [Rendition Javadoc](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/RenditionPicker.html)
3. [PrefixRenditionPicker Javadoc](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/commons/util/PrefixRenditionPicker.html)
4. [WCMRenditionPicker Javadoc](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/WCMRenditionPicker.html)
5. [PREFIX_ASSET_THUMBNAIL constant Javadoc](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/DamConstants.html#PREFIX_ASSET_THUMBNAIL)
6. [PREFIX_ASSET_WEB constant Javadoc](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/DamConstants.html#PREFIX_ASSET_WEB)
7. [UIHelper Javadoc](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/commons/util/UIHelper.html)

Comment: Without this assignment asset.listRenditions().next().getPath(), it works fine. Trying to figure out why this asset.listRenditions().hasNext() check is done .. asset.listRenditions().next().getPath() always is assigning the path of the asset as cq.web.48.48.png.

Comment: @RashmiKs You are always getting the same rendition because you ask for an `Iterator` of renditions and then you always ask for the first item, which is going to be the `48` rendition. If you use `listRenditions()`, which returns an `Iterator`, you have to iterate the result with `hasNext()` and `next()` until you get the rendition that you want.

Comment: without hardcoding how to get 640.640.png

Comment: @RashmiKs as I wrote in my answer: There is no way to get exactly the `640` rendition without hardcoding it. The best solution in that case would be to use `UIHelper.getBestfitRendition(asset, 640)`. But that is kind of hardcoded as well, with the exception that it will look for a thumbnail rendition that is _nearest_ to the specified width of `640`. So it might give you a `600` rendition (if it exists and the `640` rendition would not exist). But again: There are basically no guarantees when it comes to renditions. That's why it is so tricky ;)

Comment: I need to get 640 rendition using listRenditions() itself. But unable to know where the other renditions are available in listRenditions(). Able to see only the 48.48.png path for next().